# Advanced Custom Fields & WooCommerce possible conflict when using page rule

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a slider hero for the `woocommerce.php` template as well as custom post type that allows a user to insert additional slides to the slider with a rule that will only display the hero on the shop page.

I have then created a template part that displays the hero so I don't clogging up the `woocommerce.php` template with extra code.

At that stage I had not yet added any products to my store and the hero is displaying and working as expected with the WooCommerce notice saying there is no products in the store.

After completing the hero, I went ahead and added my first product to the store and guess what, the hero has completely disappeared. Now I'm left wondering how can I fix this? I have removed all of the CPT scripting and just echoed out a test message to see if the template is loading correctly and as expected it is, I see the test message echoed to the top of the store, where the hero should be.

I've been at trying to get this working for an hour now and I can't seem to come across anything that stands out to me. I have included the hero template part as well as the `woocommerce.php` template.

**woocommerce.php**

```php
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts
 * 
 * @package StuCowley
 * @subpackage bellezashop
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

get_header();

get_template_part( 'template-parts/hero/shop-hero' );
?>

<div class="sc-page-content">
  <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
</div><!-- /.sc-page-content -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

**shop-hero.php**

```php
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying the frontpage hero.
 * 
 * @package StuCowley
 * @subpackage bellezashop
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

if ( have_rows( 'hero_slide' ) ) :
  while ( have_rows( 'hero_slide' ) ) : the_row();
    
    $headlineHeading = get_sub_field( 'headline_heading' );
    $headlineParagraph = get_sub_field( 'headline_paragraph' );
    
    $primaryBtnTitle = get_sub_field( 'primary_button_title' );
    $primaryBtnLink = get_sub_field( 'primary_button_link' );

    $secondaryBtnTitle = get_sub_field( 'secondary_button_title' );
    $secondaryBtnLink = get_sub_field( 'secondary_button_link' );
    
    $bgImg = get_sub_field( 'background_image' );
    $bgImgOverlay = get_sub_field( 'background_overlay' );
    $bgColour = get_sub_field( 'background_colour' );
    $bgTextColour = get_sub_field( 'background_text_colour' );

    // If the hero has a background image, echo the image
    if ( $bgImg ) {
?>

<div id="shop-hero-slider">
  <section class="sc-hero-feature" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $bgImg; ?>'); background-color: <?php echo $bgImgOverlay; ?>; color: <?php echo $bgTextColour; ?> !important;">

  <?php 
  // Else if there is no background image applied, use the set background colour
  } elseif( $bgColour ) { 
  ?>

  <section class="sc-hero-feature" style="background-color: <?php echo $bgColour; ?>">

  <?php } ?>
    <div class="carousel-cell">
      <div class="sc-hero-feature-container">
        <h2 style="color: <?php echo $bgTextColour; ?>">
          <?php echo $headlineHeading; ?>
        </h2>

        <p style="color: <?php echo $bgTextColour; ?>">
          <?php echo $headlineParagraph; ?>
        </p>

        <?php if ( $primaryBtnTitle ) { ?>
        <div class="sc-hero-feature-btn-group">
          <div>
            <a href="<?php echo $primaryBtnLink; ?>" class="sc-hero-feature-btn sc-hero-feature-btn-primary">
              <?php echo $primaryBtnTitle; ?>
            </a>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( $secondaryBtnTitle )  { ?>
          <span></span>

          <div>
            <a href="<?php echo $secondaryBtnLink ?>" class="sc-hero-feature-btn sc-hero-feature-btn-secondary">
              <?php echo $secondaryBtnTitle ?>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.sc-hero-feature-btn-group -->
        <?php } ?>
      </div><!-- /.sc-hero-feature-container -->
    </div><!-- /.carousel-cell -->
  </section><!-- /.sc-hero-feature -->

  <?php
  endwhile;
  endif;
  
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
</div><!-- /#shop-hero-slider -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that immediately drew my attention was the use of "wp_reset_postdata();"

The rest indeed seems fine. [wp_reset_postdata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/)() "After looping through a separate query, this function restores the $post global to the current post in the main query". So doesn't apply here.

Also, [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) you can find more info. They don't mention "wp_reset_postdata()".

Backcheck the names of the ACF fields, and then just run something simple instead of your if else situation in order to test it out.

Since you are executing this on the woocommerce.php you might need some slight modification.

```
// Just call
// or get_queried_object_id and pass it to get_field('your_repeater_field_name', get_queried_object_id);
var_dump(get_field('your_repeater_field_name'));
```

this should throw out your data directly. If not, you'll need to pass the post object or post_id to the global $post; get_field('your_repeater_field_name', $post);

```
<?php if( have_rows('your_repeater_field_name') ): ?>
<ul class="slides">
<?php while( have_rows('your_repeater_field_name') ): the_row(); 
            ?>
    <li>
        <p><?php the_sub_field('headline_heading'); ?></p>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Alright, since I don't know exactly on which page you are executing this query and it might be the archive page, or another woo page that actually doesn't hold your ACF fields. You'll first need to:

1. Create ACF Option page -> [all details here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/)
2. Create for this Option a new field group with your slides. Or assign your slides field group also the Options (you can set OR in the conditional fields from ACF field group
3. Add data in the options page for your slider.
4. Again, get the data but instead follow the following snippet. Note that "have_rows" now have as a second parameter "option". This applies only to stored options. "repeater" place the name. [Place the following on your page.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/)

Comment: Thanks for you reply Hendrik, I have been testing and trying to get this to work. I var_dumped(); everything and I'm still coming up empty. I'm starting to think maybe this kind of functionality isn't possible with WooCommerce. I'll test and see if any hooks I'm using are causing issues

Comment: If it's empty, that means you have to use pull the post_id. If you are on archive page, that can be achieved by get_queried_object_id and pass that to the get_field as the second parameter

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this. You wouldn't happen to have a snippet of what is required here? I know it's a pain, but I think I might've headed outside of the scope of my abilities :(

Comment: Yes I know a snippet ofcourse :) will update the answer